# Detect periodical string

Tags: string, algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem, I couldn't get to linear time.

> A string T is called periodical if it can be represented in the form
>   of T=PPP..P.
>   Design a linear time algorthim for deciding whether a
>   given T is periodical,and if it's true, find the shortest period.

My approach:
if `T=AB=BA` then `T` is `periodical`, my algorithm keep checking if string can be represented like that,if yes then I check for half of it.
It takes `O(n*log(n)) time`.

Thanks guys

Comment: What did you try? Any language?

Comment: Is O(n log n) that bad?

Comment: I want to know how it's done in O(n).@user202729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KMP search algorithm computes, in part, the longest substring that's both a prefix and a suffix (shorter than the entire string).

If you apply it to a periodical string you'll get

```
len(string) - len(substring) = period
```

len(substring) must be > len(string) / 2, otherwise there's no period.

The period found will also be the shortest period.

KMP is linear.

So check it out ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)).

Comment: thanks for answer,can you tell me what do you mean by len(substring)?

Comment: @Omar that's the substring found by the algorithm.

Comment: why there is no period when, len(substring) <=len(string) / 2?

Comment: If the longest prefix that's also a suffix doesn't cover the entire source string it looks something like `abcxabc`. By the way, the condition should be strictly < not <=.