# String period in linear time

Tags: string, algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

Do you know how to find the fractional period of a string in linear time?
Some examples of what I am asking for:
input "cbcbcb"
output 2

input "qwertyd"
output 7

input "fghfghf"
output 3

I have tried to solve this problem but I can't obtain a 0(n) complexity, (n is the length of the string)

Comment: Also [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169045/how-to-find-the-period-of-a-string) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347812/given-string-s-find-the-shortest-string-t-such-that-tm-s) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442047/detect-periodical-string) and dozens more.

Comment: What is *the fractional period of a string*? (*Fractional period* seems to have other meanings in other contexts, so a search didn’t readily find the answer.)